# How to parse dynamic xml in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

any body know how to parse a dynamic xml. I have an XML with some tags. here is a tag `videos` like:

```
<Videos>
   <video>"Video link"</Video>
</Videos>
```

now in this XML, tags in `<Videos>` can be changed they could be `<video>` or `<image>` or `<clip>` or any thing else. So is it possible to parse that XML? how can i detect that tag what is the name of tag or what is in this tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [touch xml](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/source/browse/TouchXML/Common/Source/?r=SmallSocietyFork_20090625_1) to solve this issue

I am using in

> NSError * theError=nil;

```
    NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


NSString *XMLPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.xml"];

NSData *XMLData   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:XMLPath];

CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:XMLData options:0 error:nil] autorelease];



NSArray *nodes = NULL;



nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//sample" error:nil];



for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {

    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {

        //  common procedure: dictionary with keys/values from XML node

        NSString * a=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",[[node childAtIndex:counter] name],counter+1];

        [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:a];

    }


    //NSLog(@"%)
    //  and here it is - attributeForName! Simple as that.

    [item setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue] forKey:@"id"];  // <------ this magical arrow is pointing to the area of interest



    [res addObject:item];

    [item release];

}



//  and we print our results

NSLog(@"%@", res);

[res release];
```

Comment: I have used touch xml but i don't know how to detect unknown elements

Comment: @Mashhadi  see my edited answer.You can get a node in for loop

Answer (score 2):

Use TBXML and check out their guide for traversing an xml document of unknown elements...

[TBXML Guide here...](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Traversing_Unknown_elements___attributes.html)

Comment: Yeah I have used NSXMLParser, LibXML2 and TouchXML and I find TBXML the simplest and fastest library for reading xml. It doesn't do validation but if you don't need it then nothing beats it in my book!